# Power on/off button

Tags: power-supply, power-management

Are there any alternatives to Raspberry Pi that have integrated power on/off button?

In the past i managed to do it designing a small circuit, bypassing the power source with a relay,  pulling down its GPIO from C program and explicitly calling `sudo shutdown -h now` but is there any way without having to add extra circuitry?

Comment: Seems a bit off topic.  Not a question about the Raspberry Pi and sort of asking for shopping advice.

Comment: Sorry, if it is, didn't mean to. I love the Pi but its hard to prototype consumer electronics without having a built in way to power it off.

Comment: If you are prototyping consumer electronics I'd think this would be a pretty simple hurdle to overcome -- you've already admitted to doing so.  A good reason for it not to come with "the added circuitry" is because you can add it easily, and people who don't care won't want it.  Just like they won't care that it does not come with an accelerometer, gyroscope etc.  Isn't that the whole point of a *dev* board?  If you want something with everything built in, your "alternative" is a smart phone or small tablet.  Consumer electronics project done!

Comment: On/Off switch on a electric device is not a gyroscope.. but thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: Yes, there are definitely alternatives with power switch functionality - possibly other evaluation platforms without the pi's particularly shortcomings in this area, and definitely many reflashable Linux-based consumer products with a moderate amount of accessible I/O interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any alternatives to Raspberry Pi that have integrated power
>   on/off button?

AFAIK no. There are certainly add ons which can remove power from the Pi.

Speaking as an engineer, I have to ask "What is the objective"?

If it is to save power first calculate the cost of running the Pi. I did this some time ago, and it amounts to a few dollars a year - about what most of your appliances use on standby. The Pi uses little more than a PC which is "off". If you really want to save power you need to control the mains input to the power brick. It would take years to "save" the cost of the external control device.

Is it to protect the Pi? This is valid and running a shutdown is a good idea if you are not going to use the Pi for some time. This can be done from a script and it is easy to control this from a button if desired.

If you are running the Pi from batteries, particularly in a remote location, power control can be important but you need a more sophisticated solution, which should be integrated with a watchdog timer to ensure reliability.

Comment: I'm prototyping a interactive display for a client and trying to minimize the PCB part as much as possible. If there is no alternative i will include my previous circuit design but it seems like an over-engineering for such a simple and elemental task.